# SDHC memory card only readable while booting my phone

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, 5.1-lollipop, bootloader, mount

I have a 32GB SDHC memory card. It cannot be mounted normally, it says `Blank SD card , SD card is blank or has unsupported file system`. I have tried `chkdsk` on it with windows 10 which results in "RAW Drive" crap. But When I reboot my Samsung E007h in recovery mode and select "apply update from external storage" or similar option, it shows the contents(Folders) That I had created before. So why it cannot be mounted/formatted on Android and Windows? I can see all the folders from bootloader means that data is safe in there but I just can't *access* it, what should I do to mount it **OR** format it someHow to make it usable? Is there a way on **windows** to format it from **bootMenu**?
I can observe Manufacturer and all other details with `sd insight` android app.
I just want to be able to use my card normally weather I have to loose all the data or not. Doesn't matter. I can even have root access for that.